# Writing a method to serve slightly different scenarios C#

Tags: c#

I struggled with what to title this as but hopefully I can explain a little better here.  I am trying to write a program that will track an assembly through a 6 station assembly line. At each station, the operator will hit a button (such as station1start, station1stop, station2start, etc) and the button press event will send the timestamp to a database and also update the form visually by moving the traveling id number to the next station.  I have this all working for the first couple of stations but I'm wondering if there is a way to use the same method for each station.  For example have a method such as

```
void updateStart(int station_num)
```

where the station ID would be an argument but otherwise the method could be used for all of the stations.  I know that variables in C# cannot be dynamically changed but am curious if there is another way to make this code cleaner.  It seems like bad programming to have 6 methods almost identical.  Especially if we were to add another 6 stations.  See the screenshot of the form and my example code below of the button that the operator would hit when they started at station 2.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ddxww.png

```
 private void Station2Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Station2Label.Text = Station1Label.Text;
        Station1Label.Text = "";
        Station1Status.Text = "";
        Station2Status.Text = "IN PROGRESS";
        addTimeToDb(2);
    }
```

Comment: Please ask a specific question.  What do you need help with?

Comment: Also what do you mean by "I know that variables in C# cannot be dynamically changed"?

Comment: I'm wondering if you see a cleaner way to do this rather than basically writing the same code for all 12 button events?  Could an array be used somehow to change what's left of the =?

Comment: So for example if updateStart(2) was called it would know to use Station2Start.text and updateStart(3) would know to use Station3Start.Text

Comment: You can write the same code for all 12 buttons, just connect their click event to the same function and check which button sent you the click

Comment: Can you describe what do want each button to do? From code that i seen i can only say, that you can at least extract all lines to separate method like "SwitchStation(Station From, Station To);", and then call this method in all "Start button" click handlers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is somewhat unclear but I believe it is:

> I have the following code:

```
private void Station2Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Station2Label.Text = Station1Label.Text;
    Station1Label.Text = "";
    Station1Status.Text = "";
    Station2Status.Text = "IN PROGRESS";
    addTimeToDb(2);
}
private void Station3Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Station3Label.Text = Station2Label.Text;
    Station2Label.Text = "";
    Station2Status.Text = "";
    Station3Status.Text = "IN PROGRESS";
    addTimeToDb(2);
}
```

> And so on, repeated many times with minor substitutions. How do I "DRY out" this code?  (That is Don't Repeat Yourself.)

When you create the labels and status boxes put them in an array:

```
private Label[] stationLabels;
private Label[] statusLabels;
... 
// in your form initialization after the creation of the labels:
stationLabels = new [] { Station1Label, Station2Label, Station3Label, ... 
// and similarly for status labels.
```

Now write

```
private void StationClick(int station)
{
    stationLabels[station-1].Text = stationLabels[station-2].Text;
    ... and so on
```

And then each method becomes

```
private void Station2Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   StationClick(2);
}

private void Station3Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   StationClick(3);
}
```

And so on.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you so much!!   I tried to vote but im new and it wont let me vote yet.

Comment: @user2960689: You're welcome! If an answer solves your problem, click the checkmark next to it so that others know that you've found a solution.